Column value lookup based on multiple conditions and wild cards
I have a dataframe:
df = pl.DataFrame({'Col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa']
                   , 'Col2': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'f']
                   , 'Col3': ['i', 'i', 'j', 'T', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'j', 'k', 'l']
                   , 'Col4': ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 'z', 'r', 's', 'z']})
shape: (10, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Col1 ┆ Col2 ┆ Col3 ┆ Col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ a    ┆ c    ┆ i    ┆ m    │
│ a    ┆ d    ┆ i    ┆ n    │
│ a    ┆ e    ┆ j    ┆ o    │
│ b    ┆ c    ┆ T    ┆ p    │
│ …    ┆ …    ┆ …    ┆ …    │
│ b    ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    │
│ aa   ┆ d    ┆ j    ┆ r    │
│ aa   ┆ e    ┆ k    ┆ s    │
│ aa   ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

I also have a lookup criteria to compute an output column. Something like this:
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────┐
│ Col1 ┆ Col2 ┆ Col3 ┆ Col4 ┆ Output │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪════════╡
│ a    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ n    ┆ out2   │
│ a    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ out1   │
│ b    ┆ *    ┆ <>T  ┆ *    ┆ out2   │
│ aa   ┆ d    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ out3   │
│ aa   ┆ e    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ out4   │
│ aa   ┆ f    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ out5   │
│ *    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ *    ┆ Unknown│
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────┘

The last condition is essentially an Else statement.
The output would be something like this:
shape: (10, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ Col1 ┆ Col2 ┆ Col3 ┆ Col4 ┆ Output  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str     │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ a    ┆ c    ┆ i    ┆ m    ┆ out1    │
│ a    ┆ d    ┆ i    ┆ n    ┆ out2    │
│ a    ┆ e    ┆ j    ┆ o    ┆ out1    │
│ b    ┆ c    ┆ T    ┆ p    ┆ Unknown │
│ b    ┆ d    ┆ j    ┆ r    ┆ out2    │
│ b    ┆ e    ┆ k    ┆ s    ┆ out2    │
│ b    ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    ┆ out2    │
│ aa   ┆ d    ┆ j    ┆ r    ┆ out3    │
│ aa   ┆ e    ┆ k    ┆ s    ┆ out4    │
│ aa   ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    ┆ out5    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────────┘

I can write this as a cascaded pl.when(...).then(...).otherwise(...) type statement but as number of cases grows larger this could be rather awkward. Is there a better way to accomplish this type of lookup? I was considering doing a join but not sure it's possible with wildcards.

What is the expected output for the given df?

Hi - sorry - added expected output

You could brute force a join by generating all the explicit criteria rather than using wildcards (e.g. a, *, *, * becomes a, c, i, m, a, c, i, n, etc.). Alternatively, join the columns into one string and turn the criteria into a regex pattern. You'll have to be careful in applying the regex matches in the correct order.

I do not particularly like this because it creates an incredibly wide DataFrame, but it does seem to work.
Setup
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Col1": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "aa", "aa", "aa"],
        "Col2": ["c", "d", "e", "c", "d", "e", "f", "d", "e", "f"],
        "Col3": ["i", "i", "j", "T", "j", "k", "l", "j", "k", "l"],
        "Col4": ["m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "z", "r", "s", "z"],
    }
)

criteria_long = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Col1": "a", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "n", "Output": "out2"},
        {"Col1": "a", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out1"},
        {"Col1": "b", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "<>T", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out2"},
        {"Col1": "aa", "Col2": "d", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out3"},
        {"Col1": "aa", "Col2": "e", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out4"},
        {"Col1": "aa", "Col2": "f", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out5"},
        {"Col1": "*", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "Unknown"},
    ]
)

Widen criteria
Here we make a DataFrame with one row and all the criteria as columns.
criteria_wide_dict = {}
criteria_cols = criteria_long.columns
for i, row in enumerate(criteria_long.iter_rows()):
    for old_col, datum in zip(criteria_cols, row):
        new_col = f"{old_col}__{i}"
        criteria_wide_dict[new_col] = [datum]

criteria_wide = pl.DataFrame(criteria_wide_dict)

shape: (1, 35)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ Col1__0 ┆ Col2__0 ┆ Col3__0 ┆ Col4__0 ┆ … ┆ Col2__6 ┆ Col3__6 ┆ Col4__6 ┆ Output__6 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆   ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ a       ┆ *       ┆ *       ┆ n       ┆ … ┆ *       ┆ *       ┆ *       ┆ Unknown   │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────────┘

Build predicate expression
expr = pl.when(False).then(None)  # dummy starter value
for i in range(criteria_long.height):
    this_expr = pl.lit(True)  # dummy starter value

    for j, old_col in enumerate(criteria_cols):
        if old_col == "Output":
            continue

        new_col = f"{old_col}__{i}"
        this_expr = this_expr & pl.when(pl.col(new_col) == "*").then(True).when(
            pl.col(new_col).str.starts_with("<>")
        ).then(pl.col(old_col) != pl.col(new_col).str.slice(2)).otherwise(
            pl.col(old_col) == pl.col(new_col)
        )

    expr = expr.when(this_expr).then(pl.col(f"Output__{i}"))

# should never hit this otherwise, but it's good for debugging
expr = expr.otherwise(None).alias("Result")

Join and compute
df.join(criteria_wide, how="cross").with_columns(expr).select(*df.columns, "Result")

shape: (10, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ Col1 ┆ Col2 ┆ Col3 ┆ Col4 ┆ Result  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str     │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ a    ┆ c    ┆ i    ┆ m    ┆ out1    │
│ a    ┆ d    ┆ i    ┆ n    ┆ out2    │
│ a    ┆ e    ┆ j    ┆ o    ┆ out1    │
│ b    ┆ c    ┆ T    ┆ p    ┆ Unknown │
│ b    ┆ d    ┆ j    ┆ r    ┆ out2    │
│ b    ┆ e    ┆ k    ┆ s    ┆ out2    │
│ b    ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    ┆ out2    │
│ aa   ┆ d    ┆ j    ┆ r    ┆ out3    │
│ aa   ┆ e    ┆ k    ┆ s    ┆ out4    │
│ aa   ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    ┆ out5    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────────┘



I can write this as a cascaded pl.when(...).then(...).otherwise(...) type statement but as number of cases grows larger this could be rather awkward.

Even so, I believe that building a when-then expression dynamically is the simplest and fastest solution.
Here's an approach similar to the other answer but which doesn't require any kind of join:

import polars as pl


def parse_condition(cond_data: dict[str, str]) -> pl.Expr:
    condition = pl.lit(True)
    for col, value in cond_data.items():
        if value == "*":
            continue
        elif value.startswith("<>"):
            condition &= (pl.col(col) != value[2:])
        else:
            condition &= (pl.col(col) == value)
    
    return condition


def output_expression(criteria: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.Expr:
    out_expr = pl.when(False).then(None)
    for row in criteria.iter_rows(named=True):
        output = row.pop("Output")
        condition = parse_condition(row)
        out_expr = out_expr.when(condition).then(pl.lit(output))

    return out_expr


df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Col1": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "aa", "aa", "aa"],
        "Col2": ["c", "d", "e", "c", "d", "e", "f", "d", "e", "f"],
        "Col3": ["i", "i", "j", "T", "j", "k", "l", "j", "k", "l"],
        "Col4": ["m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "z", "r", "s", "z"],
    }
)

criteria = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Col1": "a", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "n", "Output": "out2"},
        {"Col1": "a", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out1"},
        {"Col1": "b", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "<>T", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out2"},
        {"Col1": "aa", "Col2": "d", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out3"},
        {"Col1": "aa", "Col2": "e", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out4"},
        {"Col1": "aa", "Col2": "f", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "out5"},
        {"Col1": "*", "Col2": "*", "Col3": "*", "Col4": "*", "Output": "Unknown"},
    ]
)

res = (
    df.with_columns(output_expression(criteria).alias("Output"))
)

Output:
>>> res

shape: (10, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ Col1 ┆ Col2 ┆ Col3 ┆ Col4 ┆ Output  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str     │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ a    ┆ c    ┆ i    ┆ m    ┆ out1    │
│ a    ┆ d    ┆ i    ┆ n    ┆ out2    │
│ a    ┆ e    ┆ j    ┆ o    ┆ out1    │
│ b    ┆ c    ┆ T    ┆ p    ┆ Unknown │
│ b    ┆ d    ┆ j    ┆ r    ┆ out2    │
│ b    ┆ e    ┆ k    ┆ s    ┆ out2    │
│ b    ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    ┆ out2    │
│ aa   ┆ d    ┆ j    ┆ r    ┆ out3    │
│ aa   ┆ e    ┆ k    ┆ s    ┆ out4    │
│ aa   ┆ f    ┆ l    ┆ z    ┆ out5    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────────┘

Note that this solution (like the other one) assumes that the rules of the criteria DataFrame are sorted by higher priority/ specificity

Yep, this is better than mine.
